# Sort the beginning of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know how to change only the beginning of an array.

For example, something like this:

```
["z","b","a"].sort(0 to 1);
```

This would be the result:

```
["b","z","a"]
```

Comment: Make a shallow copy of the part you want to sort, then sort it and copy the result back to its original index range.

Comment: The answers you're getting below are resulting in a sorted copy of the Array, so the original is not touched. Just so you know.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7426563/1759514

Comment: Here's an example that mutates the original, which is what `.sort()` does. https://jsfiddle.net/ay0n2L3b/ `arr.slice(start, end).sort().forEach((item, i) => arr[start+i]=item)`

Comment: Or like this: `arr.splice(start, end-start, ...arr.slice(start, end).sort())` https://jsfiddle.net/ay0n2L3b/1/

Comment: @squint great point. Actually I think it's a shame that there isn't a built-in sort method that doesn't mutate the original

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
arr=["z","b","a"];
arr2=arr.splice(0,2).sort();
final=arr2.concat(arr);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the section of the array you want to sort. Sort it, and put it back on with the rest of the array.

```js
var arr = ["z","b","a"];
var temp = arr.splice(0,2).sort();
arr = temp.concat(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

or the other way

```js
var arr = ["z","b","a"];
var temp = arr.splice(2);
arr = arr.sort().concat(temp);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for the wanted part, use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with the rest before returning.

```js
function sort(array, start, end) {
    var a;
    array = array.slice();
    a = array.splice(start, end - start + 1);
   
    return a.sort().concat(array);
}

var data = ["z","b","a"];
console.log(sort(data, 0, 1));
```

In situ, using the same array.

```js
function sort(array, start, end) {
    [].splice.apply(array, [0, 0].concat(array.splice(start, end - start + 1).sort()));
}

var data = ["z","b","a"];

sort(data, 0, 1);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the portion which you want to sort using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)(which also removes the elements from the array), sort them and insert into the same place using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)  method.

```
function sortPart(arr, i, j) {
  // put the sorted value in the same position from where it removed
  // you can although use spread syntax(...) instead of `apply()`
  [].splice.apply(arr,
    // put the arguments in an array
    [i, 0].concat(
      // get the portion from the original array and sort it
      arr.splice(i, j - i + 1).sort()
    )
  );
  return arr;
}
```

```js
var arr = ["z", "b", "a"];

function sortPart(arr, i, j) {
  [].splice.apply(arr, [i, 0].concat(arr.splice(i, j - i + 1).sort()));
  return arr;
}

sortPart(arr, 0, 1);

console.log(arr);
```

---

With [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) :

```js
var arr = ["z", "b", "a"];

function sortPart(arr, i, j) {
  arr.splice(i, 0, ...arr.splice(i, j - i + 1).sort());
  return arr;
}

sortPart(arr, 0, 1);

console.log(arr);
```

---

**Note :** This answer works at any index range, not only at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only sort the begining of an array from 0 to n I propose you a function you just pass length of the range to sort. In ES6

```js
var beginSort = (array, length) => array.slice(0,length).sort().concat(array.slice(length));
var input = ["z","b","a"];
console.log(beginSort(input, 2));
```